Error initializing ONNX-model from C# on Windows Server 2022: Unknown model file format version
We have an exported ONNX-model, built using Python and imported to a .NET Core 8 application.
Everything works as expected on our local machines, Windows 11 and Windows 10.
However, when deploying to the server, Windows Server 2022, we receive the following error:
Error initializing model: Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime.OnnxRuntimeException: [ErrorCode:Fail] Load model from [path to model]\modelname.onnx failed: C:\apilot\agent_work\1\s\engine\lotus\onnxruntime\core\graph\model.cc:110 onnxruntime::Model::Model Unknown model file format version.
We also have a little console app, that basically does the same thing that we have tried to run from the server - same error.
We have checked the following things:

Validated so the app has access to the ONNX-file
Checked that the correct DLL, Onnx Runtime, exist on the server

This is where it goes wrong:
var onnxScoringEstimator = mlContext.Transforms.ApplyOnnxModel(modelFile: modelFilePath, outputColumnNames: new[] { "dense" }, inputColumnNames: new[] { "embedding_input" }); 

Has anyone had a similar issue? Could it be that Windows Server 2022 doesn't support ONNX? Or is it something we are missing?

Okay, we have found the issue:
It seems like the web application looks for onnxruntime.dll in the c:\windows\system32 directory.
When we looked in the directory, it was an old onnxruntime.dll there.
We manually updated the dll and it start working.
Update:
We used the package ML.NET.OnnxRuntime.Managed, which seems to use the System32 onnxruntime dll.
We changed package to ML.NET.OnnxRuntime and then the onnxruntime.dll is grabbed from the bin-folder - as expected
